# Graphic card models on devices with 2 or more cards?

Tags: c++, directx, graphic

How can I find the models of all graphic cards on device?
I'm using `GetAdapterIdentifier()` with `GetAdapterCount()` but it gets only the integrated grahpic card. Have you a better idea?

Comment: I think, GetAdapterCount() returns the number of monitors connected to your pc. Not the number of video cards.

Comment: It might be true. I don't know

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate adapters by using IDXGIFactory1::EnumAdapters.
It took 30 seconds to find this out using the MSDN documentation.

Comment: I never heard about it. I'll check it. Thanks